# Probability of seeing $n$ buses in time $t$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving

> Suppose you go to a bus stop. The inter-arrival time between successive buses is ${\rm Exp}(\lambda)$. You arrive at time zero and leave at time $t$. Let $Y$ denote the number of buses you saw. Find the distribution of Y.

I tried to find the probability $P(Y=n)$. Now, let $t_k$ be the inter-arrival time between $(k-1)$th and $k$th bus. So I figured that $Y$ will be equal to $n$ when $\large\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t_k \lt t$ and $\large\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_k \ge t$. Thus,

$$ P(Y=n) = P \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t_k \lt t, \sum_{k=1}^{n}t_k \ge t \right) $$

Let $\tau_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}t_k$. Now, here I am making an assumption which I am not sure of, that $\{\tau_{n-1} \lt t\}$ and $\{\tau_{n} \ge t\}$ are independent events. Using this, I concluded that:
$$ P(Y=n) = P (\tau_{n-1} \lt t)\cdot P(\tau_{n} \ge t ) $$

Using properties of moment generating functions (MGF), we can show that ${\rm MGF}(\tau_n) = \dfrac{1}{(1-\frac{z}{\lambda})^n}$, so $\tau_n \sim {\rm Gamma}(n,\lambda)$.

So I concluded that:
$$ P(Y=n) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\gamma(n,t\lambda) \right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-1)}\gamma(n-1,t\lambda) \right)$$

Is this solution correct? I am worried about my concepts, as well as my assumption of independence as said above.

Answer (score 1):

It $\{\tau_{n-1}<t\}$ and $\{\tau_n\geq t\}$ would indeed be independent events then also $\{\tau_{n-1}<t\}^{\complement}=\{\tau_{n-1}\geq t\}$ and $\{\tau_n\geq t\}$  must be independent events which is evidently not the case because $\tau_{n-1}\geq t\implies\tau_n\geq t$.

You are dealing in this situation with a [homogeneous Poisson point proces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Homogeneous_Poisson_point_process) having rate $\lambda$ so that:$$P(Y=n)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\tag1$$

Note that: $$P(Y\leq n)=P(t_1+\cdots+t_n+t_{n+1}>t)$$where the $t_i$ are iid $\lambda$-exponential distributed random variables.

This can be exploited to find what is stated in $(1)$.

E.g. $P(Y=0)=P(Y\leq0)=P(t_1>t)=e^{-\lambda t}$.

---

**Edit**

I will handle here special case $\lambda=1$ for convenience.

There is no essential difference with the general case.

With induction we will prove that in special case $\lambda=1$ we have:$$P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}>t\right)=e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}\tag1$$

The base case $n=1$  is evident: $P(t_1>t)=e^{-t}$ for exponential rv $t_1$ equipped with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$.

Now $(1)$ is our induction hypothesis and we calculate:$$\begin{aligned}P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}+t_{n+1}>t\right) & =\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}+t_{n+1}>t\mid t_{n+1}=x\right)e^{-x}dx\\
 & =\int_{0}^{t}P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}+x>t\mid t_{n+1}=x\right)e^{-x}dx+\int_{t}^{\infty}P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}+x>t\mid t_{n+1}=x\right)e^{-x}dx\\
 & =\int_{0}^{t}P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}>t-x\right)e^{-x}dx+\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\\
 & =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\left(t-x\right)}\frac{\left(t-x\right)^{k}}{k!}e^{-x}dx+\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\\
 & =e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\left(t-x\right)^{k}}{k!}dx+\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\\
 & =e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[-\frac{\left(t-x\right)^{k+1}}{\left(k+1\right)!}\right]_{0}^{t}+\left[-e^{-x}\right]_{t}^{\infty}\\
 & =e^{-t}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}+e^{-t}\\
 & =e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}
\end{aligned}
$$

The third equality is based on independence of the $t_i$.

The fourth equality rests on $(1)$.

This leads to: $$P\left(Y\leq n\right)=P\left(t_{1}+\cdots+t_{n}+t_{n+1}>t\right)=e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}$$
and $$P\left(Y=n\right)=P\left(Y\leq n\right)-P\left(Y\leq n-1\right)=e^{-t}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}$$
in special case $\lambda=1$.

In the general case we get $$P\left(Y=n\right)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^{n}}{n!}$$

Comment: I am unable to translate your condition for $P(Y\lt n)$ to find $P(Y=n)$... how do we do it? I found $P(Y\le n) = 1 - \frac{\gamma(n+1,t\lambda)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$, but I am unable to proceed further...

Comment: I have added something. Further we find $P(Y=n)$ by means of $P(Y=n)=P(Y\leq n)-P(Y\leq n-1)$